# Missing $ insert issue error message

Tags: bibliographies

I'm getting an error message related to my bibliography. Here is the package I'm using. I have an URL in the reference, but I'm not sure this is causing the problem.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{PalmOilBibliography.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\printbibliography

@online{Statistics2019,
author = "Statista",
title = "\textsc{P}alm oil: \textsc{G}lobal production volume 2012/13 -- 2018/19",
year = "2019",
url = "https://www.statista.com/statistics/613471/palm-oil-production-volume-worldwide/",
urldate = "2019-03-23",
}
```

Comment: the error message would show where the problem is, but you have not shown it, normally it is due to math-only character such  as `_` which tries to stary a math subscript rather than using `\_` to produce `_`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was the math-only character _ I replaced it by  \_ as you said. Thank you!

Comment: You were lucky I had my crystal ball since you showed neither any input nor an error message with `_`  please always try to post code that reproduces the error so people cam debug it, and always show error messages in full.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comment.

Comment: `\textsc` on an uppercase letter does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The error message would show where the problem is, but you have not shown it, normally it is due to math-only character such as `_` which tries to start a math subscript rather than using `\_` to produce `_`.